# "git diff" highlight everything in green - not the new changes

Tags: git, macos, terminal

When I type 'git diff filename' it highlights all of my code in green (I did modifications to my file and CMD+S to save changes and test multiples times) instead of just the new lines... Anybody can help? Thank you guys

Comment: can you provide the results of a `git status` and the filename?

Comment: @Maus / filename is index.html / On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

 modified:   index.html

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: Could it be that the DOS/linux line ending format has changed? You could try a `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` and see if the diff changes to just the modified lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was a change in ELF format. The old flags to control this are a mess. The best thing you can do is set git to not mess with it by adding `* -text` to gitattributes. Set the files to their original EOL format (amend if it's already commited) and then everything should be back to normal.

Comment: Thank you for your response; I just had to "git add index.html" again and it worked...